# Wraping Labels in Zend_Form_Element_Radio

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form-element, zend-decorators

Maybe somebody knows. How to wrap Zend_Form_Element_Radio including Label of whole stack of radio inputs (with input labels).

```
public $radioDecorators = array(
    'ViewHelper',
    array('Description',array('tag'=>'div','class'=>'','placement' => 'prepend')),
    array('Errors',array('class'=>'error_message_show','placement' => 'prepend')),
    array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'element')),
    array('label', array('class'=>'label_text','placement' => 'prepend')),
    array(array('rows' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'radio')),
);


    $offer_type = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('offer_type', array(
                'label' => 'Label I'd like to wrap with inputs',    //Label to wrap
                'required' => true,
                'description' => '',
                'decorators' => $this->radioDecorators,
                'multioptions' => array (
                    'standard' => 'standard',
                    'premium' => 'premium',
                ),
            ));
    $this->addElement($offer_type);
```

---

Above example didn's solve my as it wraps only several inputs label's.

Comment: What do you mean by wrapping? Could you provide an example of the html you get now, and what would you like to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

I think I know what you're after and if so, you're in luck as I just had to do this the other day.

The standard ZF multi-option element separates each "option" using the `separator` property (defaults to `<br />` for radio and newline for select). This is fine for `<option>` elements but pretty shoddy for a collection of radio buttons.

The solution is to

- Add HtmlTag decorator(s) to the element, wrapping the content
- Set the separator to close and re-open the HtmlTag

For example, here's a solution to wrap the collection of inputs in an unordered list

```
$offer_type = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('offer_type', array(
    'separator' => '</li><li>',
    'decorators' => array(
        'ViewHelper',
        array(array('liWrapper' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'li')),
        array(array('ulWrapper' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'ul')),
        // the rest
    )
));
```

The alternative is to write your own view helper. Creating your own version of `formRadio` should be pretty easy.